# How to get date format in a dataframe column?

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a dataframe with a date column, and I want to convert it. With this example,

```
DF <- data.frame(name = paste("A", 1:5, sep = ""), 
                 birth = c("16131", "2014-07-04", "16257", "15982", "2014-07-04"))

as.Date(DF$birth, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

It's returning me a message error :

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  la chaîne de caractères n'est pas dans un format standard non ambigu
```

In english, the string is  in a ambiguous standard format.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're constructing your data.frame wrong. Values in `birth` are not only dates, but also integers (e.g. 16131).

Comment: Do as.Date(16131, origin = "1970-01-01") it will return a date !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some of your values require integer to Date conversion and some others character to Date. To complicate it even more, your `DF$birth` is a factor. You can split it, apply `as.Date` to the integer parts and the character parts, and then join them:

```
f <- function(x) {
    # Thanks to @RichardScriven for the improvement
    v1 <- as.numeric(v2 <- as.character(x))
    v1 <- as.Date(v1, origin = "1970-01-01")
    v2[!is.na(v1)] <- NA
    v2 <- as.Date(v2, origin = "1970-01-01")
    as.Date(ifelse(is.na(v1), v2, v1), origin = "1970-01-01")
}

f(DF$birth)
# [1] "2014-03-02" "2014-07-04" "2014-07-06" "2013-10-04" "2014-07-04"
```

Comment: You could avoid repetition by doing `v1 <- as.numeric(v2 <- as.character(DF$birth))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
as.Date(DF$birth[1], origin = "1970-01-01")
## Błąd w charToDate(x) : 
##   łańcuch tekstowy nie jest w standardowym jednoznacznym formacie
as.Date(DF$birth[2], origin = "1970-01-01")
## [1] "2014-07-04"
```

every element of birth column have to match this "1970-01-01" data pattern. Otherwise you will get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use:

```
 library(gsubfn)

 DF$birth <- as.Date(gsubfn("^[[:digit:]]+$",
 ~ format(as.Date(as.numeric(x),origin="1970-01-01"),"%Y-%m-%d"),
   as.character(DF$birth) ))
 DF$birth 
 #[1] "2014-03-02" "2014-07-04" "2014-07-06" "2013-10-04" "2014-07-04"
```